# Are Android emulators safe?

Tags: windows-10, android, malware, emulator

My question is the following...

Is it safe to use Android emulators (Nox Player, BlueStacks) on a PC, when you want to work with malicious files?

The main PC could be infected? Or is it safe?

Which would be better in that aspect... Nox Player or BlueStacks?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Android emulators are perfectly safe to run in main pc. It is recommended to download the emulators from the original website. These emulators works in a sandbox so that any dangerous APKs you install in the emulators can’t access your main pc. I use Bluestacks personally in my main pc but the downside is we have to disable HyperV. Thus we can’t use Sandbox to test unsafe windows softwares.

Answer (score 0):

Emulators provide security measures so that usually malware infecting the guest can not escape the emulated environment. However emulators often contain convenient functions for exchanging data with the host and such functions also expose a risk to the host in case a malware had taken over the emulated guest system.

On the other hand the number of malware that can pass the gap from an ARM emulator to a x86 host system is to my knowledge not very large as this is a rather uncommon situation.

But your choice of emulators is not good. Both emulators are primarily optimized for gaming. They often base on old Android systems and I doubt that they are regular updated to include the security patches Google provides.

Therefore installing malware on such an emulator may make it very easy for a malware to take over the whole guest system. And in such a case the chance that it might be able to also jump to the host system increases.

Therefore in my opinion you might better check the Android emulator from Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes, I know that both emulators mentioned are for gaming themes. But, is there any "safer" Android emulator (apart from the android studio emulator)?